# Saving Image uploaded by user to Google Cloud

Tags: c#, file-upload, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-mvc-5, google-cloud-storage

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application created with Google Cloud Tools for Visual Studio 2019. My understanding is that it is not allowed to save images to a local project folder on Google Cloud Platform.

The user uploads the image through an HTML form which POST:s to a page with the code below. The image is saved without problem when running the website locally but it does not work once published.

```
WebImage movie_poster = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest("movie_poster");
fileName = Path.GetFileName(movie_poster.FileName);
imagePath = "~/Content/img/" + movie_poster.FileName;
movie_poster.Save(imagePath);
```

I have found the Storage Bucket for my project which I can manually upload images to but I want to do it programmatically so that users can upload images on my website.

I have found [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-csharp) official documentation about uploading images to Google Cloud from code, however, the solution requires the local path to the image uploaded.

My understanding is that this full local file path can not be obtained through POST? How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using the cloud tools with a GCP virtual machine, app engine or kubernetes? I understand that you send the image through post to a server side c# and then you can save the image from there, I don't fully understand why you need to obtain the image through post (when saving the image in the c# code wouldn't the path would be known at that moment?)

Comment: I am using cloud tools with a GCP Virtual Machine combined with Compute Engine. As an alternative solution I have instead chosen to save the images to a remote FTP server however I would still like to know how to save them to Google Cloud. The code example for Google Storage API in C# needs a full local path for the image but I can not seem to obtain it from a WebImage object in C#.

Comment: As you are using compute engine first your code should save the image to the [compute engine VM](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/browse-compute) I believe you should define the full path when saving it the first time (you might want to [connect to the VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) through SSH or RDP if unsure of directory structure or if you need to modify it) and then you use the same path to feed it to the command to copy it to Cloud Storage. I am not very proficient in C# or VS with GCP extension, so I may be missing something